# If $f$ is a smooth function on a smooth manifold $M$ , then $df = 0$ if and only if $f$ is constant on each component of $M$

Tags: analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

I am reading introduction to smooth manifolds by John M. Lee.

Proposition 4.9

If $f$ is a smooth function on a smooth manifold $M$ , then $df = 0$ if and only if $f$
is constant on each component of $M$

And proof starts:

"It suffices to assume that $M$ is connected and show that $df = 0$ if
and only if $f$ is constant."

Why we can assume that $M$ is connected?

In the middle of the proof there is a sentence:

"If Let U be a connected
coordinate domain centered at $q$."

What is connected coordinate domain?

Comment: You can assume that $M$ is connected because, if it isn't, you restrict $f$ to each component and then analyse what happens on the component. Which is precisely the case of $M$ being connected, to begin with. If you do not know what a connected coordinate domain is, though, you probably have to go back and read some of the earlier chapters/sections.

Comment: I know what is coordinate domain, but i was not entirely sure about connected coordinate domain

Comment: A coordinate domain is a chart: an open set $U\subset M$ with a homeomorphism to an open set in $\mathbb R^n$. A connected coordinate domain is one where $U$ is connected.